# Running time of while-loop

Tags: while-loop, time-complexity

What is the running time of a while-loop such as this:

```
while S \not= Ø 
.....
```

i.e the running time if S (a stack) is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity should

> O(N)

if you are keep one pop up the items from the stack in each loop and N is total items in the stack.